# Setting Plex media server on Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop?

Tags: server, music, mediaserver

I just installed the **Plex media server** from the Ubuntu Software Center, and opened the web interface. I want to stream *my video , movies and music to my ps3* . I do lots of [scratched](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150909/plex-wont-enter-my-home-directory-or-other-partitions) and applied same but not working same for me .

I am having [image: Having]

/home/gaurav/Music

/home/gaurav/Movies

/home/gaurav/Videos .

In Plex from web interfaces I added [image: this] /home/gaurav/music location for Music

and

[image: this] /home/gaurav/Movies for Movies.

If finds my all Movies correctly.

*But not my all Music it only finds 11 songs* [image] out of thousand of songs [image: Music] .

What I am doing Wrong ?. Any Help would be appreciated .

Does Plex require internet for streaming videos and music to ps3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the Plex web app and ask it to scan your Music folder