# Plex Media Pretty sure its a rookie mistake but you never know.

Tags: plex

OK I see a ton of stuff for the PLEXMEDIA server. most of it hinges around permissions. I get get the server folder to show on the DLNA display but i can not get the MEDIA through. I have check the permissions they are at 770 This is desktop edition version 13.1

Am i just doing one of those rookie mistakes coming from windows. I love this system BTW i just need to get use to it

Ask me what you need IF this was a windows system i would pretty muck know what you need. I am trying to learn though. want to convert

Answer (score 0):

If the media is being served up by Plex, it may be a permissions issue. [This page](http://wiki.plexapp.com/index.php/Plex_Media_Server-Linux_Permissions_Guide) gives a good overview of setting Linux permissions and how to address them in context of running Plex at the bottom of the page. Plex does not run as a root process, but under the user `plex` so whatever directory your media is stored in has to be accessible to `plex`.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround based on: [Plex won't enter my home directory or other partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150909/plex-wont-enter-my-home-directory-or-other-partitions):

Open a terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter

`sudo gpasswd -a plex plugdev`

Verify that plex was added to the plugdev group by entering:

`groups plex`

Now open nautilus, go to `/home` (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>), right click on your "user" folder, go to ***Properties*** -> ***Permissions***, and in ***Groups***, click select ***plugdev***, and down in access select ***Access Files***.