# Getting a command to run on all files in subdirectories

Tags: 14.04, permissions, plex

Apologies for the n00b question. I've installed Plex Media Server on Ubuntu 14.04, and it seemed to be ignoring some folders and files. A very helpful person over at the Plex forums suggested I needed to ensure Plex had the proper permissions to read and access the files, and shared with me the following commands:

```
cd /directory-containing-media 
sudo find . -type d -print -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find . -type f -print -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

It's working well, but I have a lot of sub-folders/subdirectories and it's very time consuming to run in every separate folder. What's the best way to get it to run against all files in all sub-folders? I'm guessing it's to use '-r', but I'm not sure where to put it or if I need any other options etc.

Comment: The command you posted should be recursive already, are you sure it is not?

Comment: You can try chmod -R 755 * And if access denied, add sudo before the line I hope its works

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/150909/plex-wont-enter-my-home-directory-or-other-partitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands: `sudo find . -type d` and `sudo find . -type f` **finds folders and files in that directory recursively**.

```
$ whatis find
find (1)             - search for files in a directory hierarchy
```

So, It will be execulted **recursively** and find results in all **directories including all sub-directories**, for file same **works as recursively**.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very helpful and clear response.

Answer (score 0):

It will take time there is nothing you can do.

Type this 
warning first go to the desired directory after then type this 
Its to dangerous
Or change the (dot) with you desired directory path

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; 2>/dev/null >/dev/null & .
```

Your problem for time will be solved this will make you terminal free for working while your command is running on back-end.

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: What are the "type this" instructions referring to?

Comment: Its just nothing