# Plex won't list my home folder, yet I tried everything

Tags: server, mount, permissions, plex

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150909/plex-wont-enter-my-home-directory-or-other-partitions) but it didn't work. I have plex running. I have a folder /home/lucas/Downloads which is owned by lucas and its group is lucas. I added plex to that group and here's the ls -la inside /home/lucas

```
drwxrwx---+  4 lucas lucas 16384 Dez  3 00:24 Downloads
```

and yet plex won't find anything inside it. What is happening? I tried rebooting and `sudo service plexmediaserver restart` multiple times also

Comment: run this `groups plex` to see if the addition to group worked

Comment: @George it worked

Comment: add `read` to `o` user in folder `Downloads` and try to read content again

Comment: please if my last suggestion doesn't work try the given answer below as it `adds` lucas to group `plex` and not the other way round. That in my experience is how it should be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might help you. After every fresh install I add the following

sudo nano /etc/default/plexmediaserver

```
Replace the "plex" user account with your own account.

PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_USER=plex
Change to
PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_USER=lucas
```

then add lucas user to group:

```
sudo addgroup plex lucas
sudo addgroup lucas plex
```

Then to stop and start the service

```
sudo service plexmediaserver stop
sudo service plexmediaserver start
```

I add the following in .bash_aliases for easy start/stop

```
alias start='sudo service plexmediaserver start'
alias stop='sudo service plexmediaserver stop'
```

If you are trying to Limit what Plex Server can see I would look at Firejail. I use it constantly and I know you can control network connections with it so you may be able to control Plex.

sudo apt install firejail

Home Page: https://firejail.wordpress.com/

Comment: But the idea was to permit plex to only access my Downloads folder for extra security :(

Comment: even at that @GuerlandoOCs its not proper to add an app to your group remember you are owner of the system and adding an app can give it `other rights access` based on your `group rights`.

Comment: Q:But the idea was to permit plex to only access my Downloads folder for extra security :( – Guerlando OCs